Add a new field to Modern Event List - SharePoint online
I have a requirement where I would like to filter the event list.
I would like to add a new field called site with options like Project,building.
I have added the field to the list but its not showing in the modern view.
Any ideas how i can add it to the modern view?

What do you mean by "modern view"? Are you talking about list view or Events.aspx page? Can you add screenshot if possible?

Hi Gnesh, Thanks for your response. yes that what i meant the Events.aspx page

Unfortunately, you cannot customize this events.aspx page currently.

THanks Ganesh.
Are there anyways I would be able to query and display these events filtered using a custom column?

You can create a managed property based on this new column and then use Highlighted content web part to show the filtered events on page. Let me know if this works for you.
